# Getting info from PsiMethod in Intellij IDEA plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing Intellij IDEA plugin for my project, and I've faced a problem - I cannot get some ingo about method (`PsiMethod`) from my code.

First, I want to know is this method public.
And second, I want to get **fully-qualified** names of the parameter classes. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
method.getReturnTypeNoResolve().getInternalCanonicalText()
```

But it doesn't provide full name (with package name) for the standard JVM classes like `String` and `List`.

**UPDATE** First problem solved with the following code:

```
PsiUtil.getAccessLevel(method.getModifierList()) == PsiUtil.ACCESS_LEVEL_PUBLIC
```

But I still cannot get fully qualified class name

**UPDATE 2** Here is the full listing of my code:

```
Project currentProject = DataKeys.PROJECT.getData(e.getDataContext());

    PsiClass abstractComponentClass = JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(currentProject).findClass("com.mjolnirr.lib.component.AbstractComponent", GlobalSearchScope.allScope(currentProject));

    TreeClassChooser result = TreeClassChooserFactory
            .getInstance(currentProject)
            .createInheritanceClassChooser("Choose the class to generate manifest",
                    GlobalSearchScope.projectScope(currentProject),
                    abstractComponentClass,
                    false,
                    false,
                    null);
    result.showDialog();

    PsiClass classToGenerate = result.getSelected();

    List<ManifestMethod> methods = new ArrayList<ManifestMethod>();

    for (PsiMethod method : classToGenerate.getAllMethods()) {
        //  If this method is inherited from the Object class we don't need it
        if (isComponentInitialize(method)) {
            continue;
        }

        List<ManifestParameter> parameters = new ArrayList<ManifestParameter>();

        for (PsiParameter param : method.getParameterList().getParameters()) {
            parameters.add(new ManifestParameter(param.getType().getCanonicalText().replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "")));
        }

        if (method.getReturnType() != null) {
            ManifestMethod manifestMethod = new ManifestMethod(method.getName(),
                    method.getReturnTypeNoResolve().getInternalCanonicalText().replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", ""),
                    parameters);

            if (!methods.contains(manifestMethod) && isPublic(method)) {
                System.out.println("->" + method.getReturnType().getCanonicalText());

                methods.add(manifestMethod);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is weird, because `getInternalCanonicalText()` and `getCanonicalText()` both return `java.lang.String` for me. Using IDEA 12.1.6 and IDEA IU-129.713 for plugin JDK. And did you mean fully qualified name of the return type or the parameter types?

Comment: @vikingsteve both. Hm, I'll try it on 12.1.6, maybe it's bug or something

Comment: Yep, try that, and create a new IDEA JDK from 12.1.6 (IDEA IU 129.whatever)

Comment: @vikingsteve I've forgot to ask you about the edition of your IDEA - is it Community version?

Comment: @vikingsteve just checked - I have 12.1.6 Community Edition

Comment: Im using ultimate but i dont think it should matter. What is the SDK for you plugin project??

Comment: @vikingsteve JDK 1.7u45 and built-in IDEA plugin SDK. Just checked this code on Mac OS IDEA 12.1.6 - there is the same problem. Looks like a bug, don;t you think?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40439/discussion-between-skayred-and-vikingsteve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - my test IDEA instance has wrong Java SDK connected.